# Converter String de arquivo para Float em C

Tags: c, string, funções, arquivo

O programa abaixo deveria pegar os dados escritos em um arquivo .txt, mostrar na tela e fazer o cálculo de média geral.

os dados no .txt estão sendo salvos no seguinte formato:

> Aluno: Bruno
>
> Primeira nota: 5,00
>
> Segunda nota: 7,00
>
> Média:
>
> 6,00

Como é tudo salvo em string, eu preciso converter a média atual de cada aluno em float para poder fazer o cálculo.
Pesquisei em diversos sites e não entendi ao certo como utilizar a função `atof()` portanto não sei se estou utilizando corretamente, e o programa não está mostrando na tela o que está no arquivo.

Se alguém puder me dar algum auxílio quanto a utilização da função eu agradeço.

Segue abaixo o meu código até o momento.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int i = 0;
    double med , media_geral;
    char media = "0.00", linha[1000];

    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("alunos.txt", "r");
    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo Inexistente");
    }
    else
    {
        while((fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq))!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", linha[i]);
            if (strcmp(linha[i],media))
            {
                med = atof(linha[i]);
                media_geral = media_geral + med;
            }
            i++;
        }
        media_geral = media_geral/10;
        printf("Média Geral: %.2f", media_geral);
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você parece não saber direito o que é caractere e o que é string.

Em especial, esse `if` não tem nenhum sentido:

```
            if (strcmp(linha[i],media))
```

Ocorre que `linha[i]` é um caractere da linha. Esse caractere será interpretado como se fosse um ponteiro e apontando para algum lugar que não deveria apontar.

Se não houvesse esse `if` e a linha lida do arquivo for "0.00", o conteúdo do corpo do `if` iria somar zero a média geral, ou seja, não faria mal algum. Assim conclui-se que esse `if` é inútil.

Outros lugares onde você confunde caractere com string é nessas linhas:

```
            printf("%s", linha[i]);
```

```
                med = atof(linha[i]);
```

Acho que usar apenas `linha` já bastaria.

Por fim, a média é calculada ao dividir a soma dos termos pela quantidade de termos. Só que você fixou que a quantidade é sempre 10. O certo seria dividir por `i`.

Se eu entendi o seu problema direito, seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    double media_geral = 0.0;
    char linha[1000];

    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("alunos.txt", "r");
    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo Inexistente");
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while ((fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq)) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", linha);
            media_geral += atof(linha);
            i++;
        }
        if (i != 0) media_geral /= i;
        printf("Média Geral: %.2f", media_geral);
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @VictorStafusa !
Com a sua explicação eu pude perceber que meu if realmente era inútil e que eu devo estudar mais (em especial os conceitos de string)

Novamente, muito obrigado!